# How to render links based on user (extender properties) in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have some problems in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application which I am trying to render some links with information based on each user.  The menus are in the _Layout.cshtml file and the properties are in another table which has a relation one-to-one with ASPNETUsers table by the ID (Id of the user).

Here is my Model Class for the extra table that I am using:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }

    // user ID from AspNetUser table.
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(120, ErrorMessage = ("First name is required"))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(120, ErrorMessage = ("Last name is required"))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Store")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Store Store { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml which contains some links that the asp-route-id needs to change base on each user StoreId attribute.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a asp-controller="StockOnHand" asp-action="List" asp-route-id="1">List current Stock</a></li>
 <li><a asp-controller="StockOnHand" asp-action="TakeInSerial" asp-route-id="1">Receive a product</a></li>
 </ul>
```

My problem is as you seen in my layout file the asp-rout-id is hardcoded; what I need to do is that to be map to the StoreId proprerty based on the UserDetail which is linked to the ApplicationUser identity.

How can I do that? is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Julio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. One way would be to use a View Component.

[Plase see Microsoft Docs - View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components#walkthrough-creating-a-simple-view-component)

You can inject your database context directly into the View Component similar to what you do with a controller.

```
public class StoreLinksViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly yourDbContext db;

    public PriorityListViewComponent(yourDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
    string email)
    {
var storeId= db.UserDetails.Where(x => x.User.Email == email).FirstOrDefault()?.StoreId;
//create a model or ViewData here to send to your default view which is really a partial view
//then return the partial view to display in the layout view.
    }
}
```

Once created you can invoke it directly from the Layout View or any other place where it is required in the application.  You can even send the current users email as an argument:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("StoreLinks", new {email= User.Identity.Name})
```